# Where does the definition of ($\infty$-)groupoid cardinality come from?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, homotopy-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-field-theory

The *cardinality* of a finite set $X$ is the number of its elements. Once you know that, you would define the *groupoid cardinality* of a $\infty$-groupoid $X$ as the quantity
$$\lvert X\rvert := \sum_{[x] \in \pi_0 X}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \lvert\pi_n(X,x)\rvert^{(-1)^n} = \sum_{[x] \in \pi_0 X}\frac{\lvert\pi_2 (X,x)\rvert \cdot \lvert\pi_4 (X,x)\rvert \dotsm}{\lvert\pi_1(X,x)\rvert \cdot \lvert\pi_3(X,x)\rvert \dotsm}$$
when it exists. At least, I wish I could make that conceptual leap. **What are some natural ways to understand this definition of groupoid cardinality?** This has also been called the *total homotopy order* of $X$ (see e.g. the reference below) and the *homotopy cardinality* of $X$.

If $X$ is an ordinary groupoid, then
$$\lvert X\rvert = \sum_{[x] \in \pi_0 X}\frac{1}{\lvert\operatorname{Aut}(x)\rvert}.$$
This I understand probabilistically: if $X$ is a finite set with an equivalence relation $\sim$, a natural probability measure on $X/{\sim}$  weighs an orbit $[x]$ based on how likely it is that $y\in X$ is in $[x]$. Then, taking the uniform distribution on $X$ on considering this weighting, if you want to measure the "size" of $X/{\sim}$ by *weightedly* counting elements, you recover the formula in this case: $\lvert X/{\sim}\rvert = \sum_{[x] \in X/{\sim}}\frac{1}{\lvert[x]\rvert}$. This line of reasoning brings you, for example, to the statement that among finite sets, a random finite set $S$ should occur with probability $(e\lvert S\rvert!)^{-1}$, c.f. [Qiaochu Yuan's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/147039/472967) to [Cohen-Lenstra Heuristics reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146861/cohen-lenstra-heuristics-reference).

Probability here is not being used in an essential way, it's just a convenient language to talk about the "natural size" of objects. Although I would be happy to hear a probabilistic interpretation of the general definition.

I know this is also related to QM, QFTs, …. But it is not clear to me how. It is defined, for instance, in Quinn's "[Lectures on axiomatic topological quantum field theory](https://doi.org/10.1090/pcms/001/05)" in Eq. (4.4) on pp. 340 within Freed and Uhlenbeck's *Geometry and Quantum Field Theory* (1991). There's a very brief discussion there, but it builds on previous discussion I've not read. I would also like to hear a derivation coming from this perspective.

Comment: An ordinary groupoid is a 1-groupoid, no?

Comment: @HarryWilson Oops you're right. Corrected.

Comment: I do not have nearly enough understanding to really back this up, but the alternating product really smells like an inclusion-exclusion principle (albeit logarithmic). When you count a point, you overcount by a factor of $|\pi_1(x)|$, so you divide by that, but then you overcounted the amount of symmetry, so you need to multiply by $|\pi_2(x)|$, etc. Perhaps there could be a probabilistic interpretation along these lines?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'll restrict to $\pi$-finite spaces (where the definition is guaranteed to make sense).
Then homotopy cardinality is **multiplicative in fiber sequences**: if $E \to B$ is a fibration with connected base and fiber $F$,  then $|E| = |B||F|$.  To see this, use the long exact sequence of homotopy groups.  In a sense this multiplicativity is really what you're using in your probabilistic interpretation, i.e. you are using the equation $|X// G| = |X|/|G|$ that follows from $G \to X \to X//G$.  (Here note that you can remove the connectedness hypothesis if $F$ is uniform over the connected components).

Homotopy cardinality is the *only* numerical invariant with this property that extends the cardinality of finite sets.  To prove this, you can inductively show that $|K(A,n)| = |A|^{(-1)^n}$ via the fiber sequence $K(A,n-1) \to * \to K(A,n)$, and then use the Whitehead/Postnikov tower for an arbitrary $\pi$-finite space.

Comment: In fact, beyond being unique, it is universal!

Comment: Thanks, so it is the unique multiplicative (in fiber sequences) extension of cardinality along FinSet \to \pi-finite spaces.

Comment: Hi @MaximeRamzi, what exactly is the universality statement here?

Comment: You can phrase both "multiplicative along fiber sequences" and "additive on path components" with values in an arbitrary ring - or in fact just a rig, that is, you don't need additive inverses -, and the initial such function is the one with values in $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb Q_{\geq 0}$ if you don't like additive inverses